# Which makes a stronger suggestion: subjunctive or should clause?

Tags: subjunctives

> (i) It is important that she **be** reinstated immediately.
>   [subjunctive]
>  (ii) It is important that she **should be**
>   reinstated immediately. [tensed]
>  (The Cambridge Grammar of the
>   English Language)

What is the semantic difference between the two?

Comment: Either is just dandy. *Be* is probably more common in US, but is gaining new life in UK. The choice is really idiolectal: I may write *be* and see, first, my client change it to *is* and then the client's lawyers change it to *should be*.

Comment: I don't think either is stronger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per *Oxford English Dictionary* "should" firstly expresses advisability (as opposed to obligation), so I would think that the second sentence is weaker.

Comment: In the U.S., many people (like me) never use the "should" variation. And I believe that in the U.K., where the mandative subjunctive is dying, many people never use the first version. So I would have thought that they're alternative ways of saying the same thing, and that neither is stronger.